construction of $\hat{\Gamma}(K)$ knot Floer invariant
I'm reading Jonathan Hanselman's paper HEEGAARD FLOER HOMOLOGY AND COSMETIC SURGERIES IN $S^3$, https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.06773 .
In page 4, section 2, an invariant $\hat{\Gamma}(K)$ is introduced, and the author described it and gave some good properties. However, I don't see how this invariant is constructed. I'm familiar with the Ozsváth and Szabó setting of knot Heegaard Floer homology. Could anyone please tell me how the invariant $\hat{\Gamma}(K)$ is constructed and why it is equivalent to the $UV=0$ truncation of the knot Floer complex. Please tolerate my poor English and foolishness. Thanks a lot!
